# How to run large number of linux command from java application

Tags: java, linux, process, socat

I already can run Linux commands from the java app by creating a process builder and then execute by that process. I am also tailing the logs/output of that command as I need to parse them and do some other stuff. I am actually running `socat` from java.

But how to run hundreds or thousands of this command and tail them? is this even possible? I am using socat for IP forwarding and I need thousands of this concurrent forwarding rule to be active which will start/destroy by my signaling service. Whenever I tries to run thousands of socat services, the server's load average went to skyrocket and started halting.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to run thousands of "socat" commands easily. Actually, I was struggling with other commands ("lsof -t -i:port" - which I solved later personally) which were taking longer time to be completed. I was able to run 30k SOCAT processes within 30-40 sec time without parsing the output.

** And not appreciating the neg vote in the question without even commenting on a single line.